# SQL Server 2008 Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm not new to SQL Server but I am new to triggers. I've read a few tutorials and to be honest the syntax is still a little confusing.

I'm trying to create a trigger that checks for a field being set to a specific value and then update another field in the same table.

Hopefully the code below will speak for itself and the problem will be obvious to someone

```
ALTER TRIGGER updateCompletedDate
ON projects
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
   IF UPDATE(status)
   BEGIN
        UPDATE projects
        SET date_complete = GETDATE()
        FROM inserted
        WHERE inserted.status = 'Completed'
          AND projects.date_complete = '1900-01-01'
END
```

The above code doesn't have the effect I'd hoped for. When I update a row and set the status to `Completed` the `date_complete` column remains at the default of `1900-01-01`.

Thanks

As per marc_s' comments I modified the trigger to the following which now works.  The fix was the addition of `AND inserted.id = projects.id` in the where clause.

```
ALTER TRIGGER updateCompletedDate
ON projects
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(status)
BEGIN
    UPDATE projects
    SET projects.date_complete = GETDATE()
    FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.status = 'Completed'
    AND inserted.id = projects.id
    AND projects.date_complete = '1900-01-01'
END
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't see how you're *linking* those rows that were inserted/updated in the `Inserted` pseudo table to the rows in your `Projects` table. There should be something like `inserted.ID = projects.ID` or something like that in the `WHERE` clause. Also: is the `date_complete` really that value, or is it `NULL` in the database and just shown as `1900-01-01` in the GUI? Also: be **careful** with `DATETIME` column since they also include a **time** portion!

Comment: First try using trigger without the condition "AND projects.date_complete = '1900-01-01'". If worked perfectly then the problem is with the date comparison.

Comment: Cheers guys.  marc_s - the date field is defaulted to '1900-01-01'.  Not null.  Like I said I'm pretty new to triggers so I'll look into an inserted.id = projects.id comparison in the where clause.  Veera - thanks I'll look into that too.

Comment: Does this trigger triggers himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you're linking those rows that were inserted/updated in the `Inserted` pseudo table to the rows in your `Projects` table. There should be something like

```
inserted.ID = projects.ID
```

or something like that in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE p
SET 
    p.date_complete = GETDATE()
FROM  
    dbo.Projects p
INNER JOIN 
    inserted i ON inserted.id = projects.id
WHERE 
    i.status = 'Completed'
    AND p.date_complete = '1900-01-01'
```

Comment: While I haven't tried the above example I'll still mark this as the answer since your original comment regarding linking the inserted table and the projects table was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below trigger changes. I just made some minor changes.

```
ALTER TRIGGER updateCompletedDate
ON projects
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   IF UPDATE(status)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @status AS VARCHAR(20)
        DECLARE @ID AS INT

        SELECT @status = status,  @ID = ID FROM INSERTED

        UPDATE projects
        SET date_complete = GETDATE()
        WHERE @status = 'Completed'
        AND id = @ID 
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), date_complete, 101) = '1900-01-01'
    END
END
```

Comment: Hi Veera this didn't work for me unfortunately but based on marc_s's comments I've managed to get it working.  Thank you both very much.  I'll edit the question now to include the fix.